# Censor screencasts and/or screenshots for ios

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, screencast

I would like to know if it's possible to censor or hide in some way sensitive data when doing an screencast of an app from the iPhone.

For example, I'm streaming an app and at the moment I'm logging in, the username field, password field and keyboard get censored or hidden in the streaming while it still looks normal on the actual screen of the device.

So far the "closest" solution I found was to detect wether a recording is being done (explained [here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/detecting-screen-capturing-in-ios-11-cca15881c785)) and when true, I add a blurred view on top of the information I don't want to show. That will off course protect the sensitive data from being streamed BUT the user of the actual device won't be able to see it either.

Any suggestions?